# Arduino: call digitalWrite within a same naming class-member

Tags: arduino-c++

let me describe as following:

```
class foo{
public:
[...]
digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t  function){
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, LOW);  // <<== CALLS foo::digitalWrite(...
  delayMicroseconds(1); 
  SPI.beginTransaction(settings);
  SPI.transfer16(this->m_txFrame);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);  // <<== CALLS foo::digitalWrite(...
  }
 [...]
};`
```

For that Arduino has no encapsilation for digitalWrite, the beaviour ist as expected. Is there another solution except renaming foo:digitalWrite(...) I do not know yet?

Thanks in advance!

Joerg

Comment: If it is in the global namespace - and I believe it is - use `::digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);`

Comment: Thanks for your tuition. It helped! BTW: digitalWrite is a global namespace in Arduino declared in wiring_digital.c